# Cannot assign color to content attribute in before pseudo selector in Safari of iPad

Tags: css, ipad, safari, cross-browser, pseudo-element

```css
.check {
  color: green;
  font-size: 32px;
  
}

.check:before {
  content: "\2714";
}
```

```html
    <span class="check"></span>
```

### Opening this on iPad's Safari :

#### expected :

[image]

#### actual :

[image]

As you see, the content of `:before` (✔️) has the green color.

If we run the same code on **iPad Safari** browser , the (✔️) is still black and does not take the color of `span`.

I tried adding the color again inside `:before` , however , it does not work:

```
.check:before {
  content: "\2714";
  color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari mobile having font problem, to fix it you can use `FontAwesome`. It's using the same pseudo but it worked (because of its font):

```
.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.fa-check:before {
    content: "\f00c";
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ydmt80g7/27/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by :

- adding HTML fontawesome icon inside SPAN
- removing the CSS rule `:before`

```css
.check {
  color: green;
  font-size: 32px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c3ef28c600.js"></script>


 <span class="check">
   <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI: Here is a list of safe icons I found work on both desktop browsers and iOS.

Fixed an issue for me with a right black arrow showing as an emoji like icon on iOS.

https://tutorialzine.com/2014/12/you-dont-need-icons-here-are-100-unicode-symbols-that-you-can-use